# Reading an ADT from a ByteString

Tags: haskell

Let's say we have a data type like

```
data Letter = A | B | C
```

and we get a `ByteString` input that contains "A".
How do we easily transform that `ByteString` into a `Letter` type?

P.S. I found the [Readable](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/readable) library that does this, however it returns a `MonadPlus` (that I'm not very familiar with) instead of a `Maybe Letter` that I would expect.

---

Edit:

Here is the simple HTTP app I'm working on for context. I can't seem to be able to get a `Maybe Letter` with this.

```
import Network.Wai
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Network.Wai.Handler.Warp (run)

app :: Application
app request respond = let letter :: Maybe Letter
                          letter = fmap fromBS $ getParam request "letter"
                      respond $ responseLBS status200
                                            [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
                                            "hello"

getParam request name = join (lookup name (queryString request))
```

The compiler complains about a type error and I can't figure out how to capture these two types `m0` and `a0`, not even if I write something like `let letter :: Maybe (Letter, ByteString)` in line 7 instead.

```
• Couldn't match type ‘m0 a0’ with ‘Letter’
  Expected type: Maybe Letter
  Actual type: Maybe (m0 a0)
```

Comment: What should be if the input stream hasn't `"A"` or has something else?

Comment: Well, given the definition of `Letter`, I would expect that `readBS "A"` returns `Just A` and `readBS "X"` returns `Nothing`. I would like to avoid writing unnecessary code and it sems to me that this kind of simple deserialization could be supported somehow elegantly in Haskell.

Comment: What text encoding do you expect (`ByteString` is just "list" of bytes)?

Comment: If you're flexible about the format of the bytestring you take (eg. not necessarily a string representing "A"), then just use a serialisation library like [cereal](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/cereal) (either using its automatically generated `get`/`put` functions or writing your own).

Comment: Actually, I'm working on a simple HTTP server in which I use Wai+Warp only. I get a `ByteString` out of a [Query](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types-0.12.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Types-URI.html#t:Query), so I suppose that's a UTF8-encoded ByteString.

Comment: @hvth If you're expecting string data in UTF8, you should use [`QueryText`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/http-types-0.12.1/docs/Network-HTTP-Types-URI.html#t:QueryText).

Comment: Ah, cool! Thanks, @hnefatl, I'll switch. However my predicament still persists :)

Comment: Maybe is a MonadPlus, so the Readable would work for you

Comment: @max630 I expanded my question a bit to explain why I'm having trouble with treating the MonadPlus as a Maybe. It has to do with these two types I don't understand: `m0` and `a0`.

Comment: probably your getParam has already one Maybe, and another comes from fromBS, so the letter's type would be `Maybe (Maybe Letter)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The general approach is to derive a `Read` instance which provides deserialization from a `String`:

```
data Letter = A | B | C deriving (Read)
```

via `read`, `reads`, `readMaybe` and other variations defined in `Text.Read`, and then use a conversion function (such as `Data.ByteString.Char8.unpack`, if the byte string is ASCII or Latin-1) to convert from the bytestring to a string.

The details of what you're trying to do are a little fuzzy.  (For example, if the bytestring is "ABC", do you want to parse the "A" and save the "BC" for later, or should that yield `Nothing`.)  However, the following may get you started:

```
import Text.Read
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C

data Letter = A | B | C deriving (Show, Read)

readLetter :: C.ByteString -> Maybe Letter
readLetter = readMaybe . C.unpack
```

Testing it in GHCi:

```
> :set -XOverloadedStrings
> readLetter "A"
Just A
> readLetter "B"
Just B
> readLetter "X"
Nothing
> readLetter "ABC"
Nothing
>
```

Comment: This is nice! Since I saw that Wai/Warp expect one to work with `ByteString`s I totally ignored the fact that I could just transform them into plain `String`s.

Answer (score 4):

Typed not tested:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import Data.ByteString.Char8 as BC
-- ^^ Replace if you want an encoding besides ASCii

data T = A | B | C deriving (Eq,Ord,Show)

f :: ByteString -> Maybe T
f x | x == "A" = Just A
    | x == "B" = Just B
    | x == "C" = Just C
    | otherwise = Nothing
```

Comment: This is totally pragmatic, but seeing as I have 5-6 of such ADTs and some of them have up to seven constructors, I'd like to avoid writing this kind of code for each of them.

Answer (score 2):

> it returns a MonadPlus (that I'm not very familiar with)

`Maybe` has a `MonadPlus` instance, so you could just use that.

Comment: I expanded my question a bit to explain why I'm having trouble with treating the MonadPlus as a Maybe.